# Ajax & jQuery: Sending data to php script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("a.star").click(function(e){ 

e.preventDefault(); 

var dataID = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/engine/save.php",
    data: "id=dataID"
    success: {

         alert("FFS WORK " + data);

    }
});
return false;
});


<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="7" class="star">test</a>
```

How can I send data-id to save.php (/engine/save.php?id=7) successfully? Tried just about everything and no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just with

```
data: { id : dataID },
```

the benefit of using an object (instead of a string concatenation) is that you don't need to worry to escape the value passed along with the ajax call

Comment: I changed the data to this but it's still not processing anything to /engine/save.php. I wonder if there is an error in my syntax?

Comment: you should also add a comma `,` before `success:` (look at your js console)

Comment: Found it just after posting. Tar. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
url: "/engine/save.php?id=" + dataID
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should understand how to concatenate a string with a js variable. You should use `+` operator to concatenate a string and a js variable.

Use this

```
data: "id=" + dataID;
```

You can also send it as an object `jQuery` will take care of attaching it to the request.

```
data: { id: dataID }
```

Comment: I see. This wasn't the actual problem with my code though. Even when changed to these the data will not be passed to /engine/save.php. :( Is there a problem with my syntax at all?